# Fundamental form of almost complex manifold is $(1,1)$-form

Tags: differential-forms, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds, tangent-spaces, almost-complex

Let $M$ be an almost complex manifold with almost complex structure $J$, a compatible Riemannian metric $g$ and fundamental form $\omega$. Consider the eigenspaces $T_p^{1,0}M=\{v\in T_pM\otimes\mathbb{C}:J_pv=iv\}$ and $T_p^{0,1}M=\{v\in T_pM\otimes\mathbb{C}:J_pv=-iv\}$ of the tangent spaces to $M$ at some point $p$. I need to show that:

- $\omega_p(u,v)=0$ for $u,v\in T_p^{1,0}M$
- $\omega_p(u,v)=0$ for $u,v\in T_p^{0,1}M$

For this, we consider of course the complex linear extension of the maps involved. I know that $\omega_p(u,v)=g_p(J_pu,v)$ by definition of the fundamental form and that $g_p(J_pu,J_pv)=g_p(u,v)$ by compatibility of the metric. But I do not manage to prove the two results. Can sombebody help me here?

And how can I dedude that the fundamental form is a $(1,1)$-form, ie. $\omega\in\Omega_M^{1,1}$? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$\omega_p(J_pu, J_pv) = g_p(J_p(J_pu), J_pv) = g_p(J_pu, v) = \omega_p(u, v)$$

for any $u, v \in T_pM\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}$. Now consider how to simplify the left-hand side when $u, v \in T^{1,0}_pM$ or $u, v \in T^{0,1}_pM$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know that in the case $u,v\in T_p^{1,0}M$, we have $J_pu=iu$ and $J_pv=iv$. With this, I obtain $\omega_p(J_pu,J_pv)=\omega_p(iu,iv)=i\cdot(-i)\cdot\omega_p(u,v)=\omega_p(u,v)$ which doesn’t really help... I’m sorry but I don’t really see what else I could do here.

Comment: To regard $\omega$ as a complex form, it is extended complex bilinearly, so we have $\omega_p(iu, iv) = i^2\omega_p(u, v)$, not $i(-i)\omega_p(u,v)$.

Comment: Then it would work, yes. But I have seen in my lecture that I have to take the conjugate when taking out the factor of the second component, so I’m not quite sure here.

Comment: And how does this result tell me that $\omega$ is a $(1,1)$-form?

Comment: You are probably thinking of a hermitian metric, not a differential form. As $\omega$ is a two-form, it has $(2, 0)$, $(1, 1)$, and $(0, 2)$ parts. As $\omega(u, v) = 0$ for all $u, v \in T^{1,0}_pM$, the $(2, 0)$ part of $\omega$ is zero, and likewise, as $\omega(u, v) = 0$ for all $u, v \in T^{0,1}_pM$, the $(0, 2)$ part of $\omega$ is also zero, so $\omega$ is a $(1, 1)$-form.